# Sending mp4 file from android device via UDP packets

Tags: android, udp

I have basic knowledge of udp sockets in android  , i have already send text string from my android phone to pc(in which i have a java program to receive it) , but i don't know how to send a 3gp song via UDP sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach for packing data so you can be able to send it over a network is called [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

The most common libraries about this are the [Boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) and [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).

Comment: @charlie and this is basically what the serialization is for, but this libraries are much better than anything you can write from scratch, also you need to handle the coding and decoding phase, the main concept is what you describe but it's not that trivial so probably you want to stick with those libraries.